# iTextSharp Textfield setting the font to Bold

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

For a textfield object, I would like to change the style to bold. I have already created the arial font since it is not a default font for the BaseFont object. Apparently the TextField object only takes the BaseFont as a valid font. I was wondering how would I change the style of the font that I have assigned to my textfield to bold. Is there a way to do this? here is my code that I have thus far

```
TextField txtNewField = new TextField(stamp.Writer, new Rectangle(1, 1, 75, 25), "TxtField"); 
BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED); 
txtNewField.FontSize = 8; 
txtNewField.Font = arial;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried specifying `arialbd.ttf` as the font name? I think that will give better results anyway, as the bold font will have been tuned.

(I'm not sure why you can't just specify a `Font` for a TextField, admittedly...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in all cases, but I created this helper method for adding a form field. It abstracts away calculating upper right X and Y values and also deals with making the font bold.

It hides some of the nasty implementation details from the caller.

Credit to @jon-skeet for helping me solving the bold font problem!

```
        private static void AddFormField(PdfWriter pdfWriter,
            float lowerLeftX,
            float lowerLeftY,
            float width,
            float height,
            string fieldName,
            Font font)
        {
            var upperRightX = lowerLeftX + width;
            var upperRightY = lowerLeftY - height;
            var fontName = font.Style == Font.BOLD ? $"{font.Familyname}-Bold" : font.Familyname;
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontName, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            var box = new Rectangle(lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY, upperRightX, upperRightY);

            var field = new TextField(pdfWriter, box, fieldName)
            {
                Font = baseFont,
                FontSize = font.Size
            };

            pdfWriter.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField());
        }
```