# How to bold words for use with PdfWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to bold certain words i am going to insert into my pdf file. The words can be found after my table.addcell("words"). I bold it in order to identify between the data and the label.

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop\\New folder", filename), FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output);
        doc1.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        ////actual width of table in points
        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        ////fix the absolute width of the table
        table.LockedWidth = true;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, mr.citizenreport, aor.officialreport from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OFFICIAL REPORT "));

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            table.AddCell("Full Name :\r\r "+ dr[0].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Contact :\r\r "+ dr[1].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Type Of Crime :\r\r "+ dr[2].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Location :\r\r "+ dr[3].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Citizen Report Date Time :\r\r "+ dr[4].ToString());
            table.AddCell("PoliceID :\r\r "+ dr[5].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Police Report Date Time :\r\r "+ dr[6].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Police Report :\r\r "+ dr[7].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Citizen Report :\r\r"+ dr[8].ToString());
            table.AddCell("Admin Official Report :\r\r"+ dr[9].ToString());

        }

        dr.Close();
        doc1.Add(table);
        doc1.Close();

    }
```

I tried using chunk and it doesn't seems to work either.

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Full Name", FontFactory.GetFont("dax-black") + table.AddCell(dr[0].ToString()));
```

**UPDATE**
Finally able to format the word 
[Return true when chunk is used iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952771/return-true-when-chunk-is-used-itextsharp)

Comment: you probably want to add some `Chunk`s tot he cells; there's some examples on working with Chunks at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/82/iTextSharp-Adding-Text-with-Chunks-Phrases-and-Paragraphs

Comment: I think `<b>` and `</b>` will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628473/different-format-into-one-single-line-interop-word/10076425#10076425

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564073/how-do-i-write-bold-text-to-a-word-document-programmatically-without-bolding-the

Comment: @Freelancer the link you gave me are bolding a string of label as i have read them before posting. However if you see my codes above, my label are placed inside the addcell of the pdf. Hence, i tried the method from the links and it didnt work.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I tried using chunk on within my datareader method on my datareader and it doesnt work. 

    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Full Name", FontFactory.GetFont("dax-black") + table.AddCell(dr[0].ToString()));

Comment: @Shekhar those are html tag to bold words and i'm pretty sure it doesn't work for my label.

Comment: Has "dax-black" been loaded using an absolute path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497124/itextsharp-textfield-setting-the-font-to-bold

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm not very sure. I get the code from some tutorial site. It just wanted the label to be bold though. And i think it is something different from others as the label is within a addcell method.

Comment: See the link I posted for how to explicitly create fonts from an actual file path. iTextSharp doesn't automatically look in your fonts folders for fonts (although you can tell it to do that).

Comment: I get what you meant by explicitly creating font from an actual file path. But as you can see from my codes, I dont really see a way for me to link this explicitly created font into my label within my datareader method.

Comment: I have tried using chunk as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952771/return-true-when-chunk-is-used-itextsharp