# Bold letters on iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am writing a simple program on CSharp. What it does, is that you write a text(in a richTextBox), and it saves it's content on a .pdf in a specific path. Now, i want the user to target a specific word/phrase, and by clicking a button, the specific word/phrase will go bold. Is this possible ?? And if yes, how ??

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497124/itextsharp-textfield-setting-the-font-to-bold Looks like changing the font name might help

Comment: I don't want to make all the phrase bold. I whant the user to specify which words will go bold.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check this out : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/81/itextsharp-working-with-fonts

What basically you need to do is to call the SetFieldProperty function
You take your old pdf, edit it and out put a new PDF with a bolded textbox.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); //Memory stream to with new pdf with changed bold text
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("file.pdf"); //The original PDF
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream); //A stamper to create the pdf

SetFieldProperty("fieldName","textfont",BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD,null);   //Change textbox properties

SetField("fieldName","TEXT"); //Change field text

stamper.Close(); //Save and close
byte[] newFile = stream.ToArray(); //Here you have your new file with the bolded text
```

This code will give you a new file with the bolded text

Comment: I got this error: http://prntscr.com/a12psw

Comment: Ill expand on my anwser

Comment: You may want to go to the basics and read this: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-8

Answer (score 0):

I think you can input an html to itextsharp. This way you can control many styling attributes using html. for ex: This is **bold** text. can be input as :

```html
This is <b>bold</b> text.
```

You can use Html to customize the styling and color of the text like this. Although I haven't tried using external stylesheets using itextsharp, but the inline styling works fine.